# Не корректно идет проверка по POST

Tags: jquery, php, регистрация

Написал проверку на корректность и занятость E-mail адреса у пользователей, но почему-то POST запрос идет не правильно. Запрос идет больше секунды и почему-то нельзя использовать ответ от запроса в условии

```
<script>
            if(email == '') {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#email").addClass('input_error');
                $('#error_reg').show();
                $('#error_reg_info').text('Необходимо заполнить все поля');
            } else {
                var resEmail = email.search(/[-0-9a-z_]+@[-0-9a-z_]+\.[a-z]{2,6}/i);
                if(resEmail == -1){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#email").addClass('input_error');
                    $('#error_reg').show();
                    $('#error_reg_info').text('Неверный формат Email');
                } else {
                    var url = host+"/resources/classes/testEmail.class.php";
                    $.post(url, { email: email},
                    function(data){
//Если здесь вывести ответ, то он работает ( alert(data); )
                        if(data == 'no') {                  
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $("#email").addClass('input_error');
                            $('#error_reg').show();
                            $('#error_reg_info').text('E-mail занят');
                        } else {
                            $("#email").removeClass('input_error');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
</script>

<?php

include '../basic/config.php';
include '../basic/function.php';

$email = tm($_POST['email']);

$query = "SELECT `id`
FROM `users`
WHERE `email`='{$email}'
LIMIT 1";

$sqle = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($sqle)==1)
    {
        echo "no";
    } else {
        echo "yes";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот в чем смысл проверять на JS'e? Его можно убрать и сделать запрос? Я вообще не вижу смысл проверок на клиентской части. Сразу, без проверок подавайте где вам нужно будет написать только одну строчку используя функцию `filter (FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`, в пхп все есть).